# Change Value of function arguments in Java

Tags: java, c

I need to convert C code to Java.
The minimal C code is:

```
void changeX(int *x)
{
    *x=5;
}
```

changeX is called in function B as:

```
void B()
{
    int k= 2;
    changeX((int*) &k);
}
```

The problem while converting it into Java is that x is not a class member so i cannot use this. How can i convert such code to Java?

Comment: Perhaps you cannot convert simply, reliably and automatically C code to Java. Do you have another way to solve your problem?

Comment: My C is quite rusty but does that C code actually do what you think it does?

Comment: And your example will probably crash (because it is dereferencing an int at address 0x2), but Java don't have crashing behavior... Or perhaps you mean `changeX((int*) &k);` in the body of `B` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're really asking, "Can I use pass-by-reference in Java" (which that C code isn't using, but is emulating with pointers, which also aren't supported in Java) the answer is no.

Options:

- Pass in a reference to an object which *does* contain a field you can change
- (Ugly, but equivalent to the above in some senses) Pass in an array of size 1 constructed using the local variable, mutate the variable in the method, and then set the local variable again based on the array contents afterwards
- Return the new value and assign it that way
- Change your design so you don't need this

The last two of these options are the nicest ones. If you could give more information about the bigger picture - *why* you think you want to do this - that would be helpful.

Comment: How can i use the wrapper class here?

Comment: @RogMatthews: Like the array: create a wrapper class, instantiate it using the local variable, pass in the reference to the wrapper, mutate the wrapper in the method, then back in the caller either set the local variable again from the wrapper or use it directly. It's ugly though - a redesign would be better.

Comment: Did you mean "change your design" for option 4?

Comment: @RogMatthews: It's just a class with a getter and a setter - there's nothing tricky here. You could make it generic so you only need to write it once - but as I say, I'd recommend *against* this approach anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use one-element array reference:

```
void changeX(int[] x) {
  // do not forget about checks
  x[0] = 5;
}

void test() {
  int[] x = {0};
  changeX(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Being a primitive, and not a class member, you cannot pass the reference to another method. Use a class member instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the new value of x,the method should as follow:

```
private int changeX(int x){
    return 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You existing C code is incorrect:

```
void B()
{
    int k= 2;
    // you are not passing address of variable k but instead
    // you are passing k (which is 2) as the address whose location needs 
    // to be changed. So you are writing to address 2 which you don't own.
    changeX((int*) k);
}
```

What you need is:

```
changeX(&k);
```

Now this is changing the value of a variable by passing it by address. Now such a thing is not possible in Java which always uses pass by value. But you can get similar effect by enclosing the int variable inside an Integer object or an integer array (also an object) and pass the object by value.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the Java question though.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Was updating the answer.

Comment: Note that the C code is using pass-by-value as well - it's just that the value it's passing is a pointer to a variable, and *that* isn't supported in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put Java has no equivalent to a pointer to a basic type - in order to achieve this you need a reference int type something like

```
class RefInt {
  public int Value;
  RefInt(int x) { Value=x; }
}
```

And you pass this in the same context and it works like so:

```
RefInt X=new RefInt(3)
ChangeX(X);
```

Obviously in this context simply changing the return value to type int and assigning it would be better but that doesn't solve your general problem.

Answer (score 0):

Option1:
Put the int variable in a wrapper class. Pass that the method. In the method you can change the value in wrapper instance.

Option2:
Make changeX() return int and replace all changeX(k) with k = changeX(k).